# SQLite Insert NullException?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, nullpointerexception

For some reason my code returns a NullException when trying to insert into a table? I am extremely confused.

```
try{
        if(contactsh.selectAll().size() > 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < contactsh.selectAll().size() - 1; i++){
                names[i] = contactsh.selectAll().get(i);
            }
        } else {

        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        contactsh.insert("Example"); //ERROR IS HERE
        timeh.insert("20:20");
        dateh.insert("06/27/27");
        txth.insert("1-555-555-5555");
        Log.w("initiate contacts error: ", e.toString());
    }
```

Error:

```
06-19 11:29:55.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9482): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 11:29:55.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at com.laytproducts.timexter.mainAct.onCreate(mainAct.java:57)
06-19 11:29:55.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-19 11:29:55.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2701)
06-19 11:29:55.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9482):     ... 11 more
```

Here is my insert method in my class for the DatabaseHelper:

```
public long insert(String name){
    this.insertStmt.bindString(1, name);
    return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
}
```

If you need to see my whole class I will be more than happy to post it here.

Comment: Need to follow your helper classes down further to help you.   Lets see what you're using for `insertStmt` and it's `executeInsert()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will probably need to see more code, but I expect either `this.insertStmt` is null or `contactsh` is null.

Comment: wow I think you are right. Brain fart... I didn't define the contactsh (new ContactDatabase()). 

Thanks I think it worked.